# How to import a custom JS file into a React Single Page App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

The question is simple although the approach can vary.

First I am using the following:

1 - Webpack
2 - Babel
3 - ES6
4 - npm

I have the module `Bootstrap` included but can't figure out how to call the JS file via `import`

This is how I'm approaching it:

`import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap';` and that doesn't work so my first problem is not being able to access bootstrap so i can't even begin to figure out how to access the `bootstrap.js` file.

The second approach was to scrap the idea of accessing Bootstrap from the `node-modules` folder and just add `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` to the `src` directory in my React build.

What I then tried was to access bootstrap css like this:

`import './css/bootstrap.css';` and that works fine.

But when i attempt to `import`, `bootstrap.js` like this `import './js/bootstrap.js` I get an error when React tries to compile.

[image]

The image above shows how I'm trying to import my local `JS` file.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

I would love either a solution using the `bootstrap` module (which is cleaner so I don't have to manually include) but would also like to know how to manually include as well.

Thank you.

Comment: why are you importing your css and libraries in like that? use html script / link tags. You are trying to import styles in javascript (big no no) and your libraries too.. when they should be done in your html file

Comment: Importing CSS like that is completely fine if you are using WebPack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the bootstrap WebPack package.

https://github.com/gowravshekar/bootstrap-webpack